# Haskell type declaration problem with isSquareNumber function

Tags: haskell, sqrt, type-declaration

I have to write a function that determines if a number is a perfect square, which I was able to do:

```
isSquareNumber x
    | x < 0 = False
    | otherwise = snd (properFraction (sqrt x)) == 0.0
```

But I have to use a given type declaration: `isSquareNumber :: Int -> Bool`

Whitout it, it works fine, but when I add it I get errors.

Comment: Floating point numbers do have some trouble when they're big.  For instance, `10000000000000001` is not a perfect square, but your function will return True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) does not work with an `Int`, but with `Floating` types, and an `Int` is not an `Floating` type.

You can use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert an `Integral` type to any `Num` type. You thus can implement this as:

```
isSquareNumber :: Int -> Bool
isSquareNumber x = x >= 0 && f == 0.0
    where (_, f) = properFraction (sqrt (fromIntegral x))
```